# Update mac app source code

Tags: python, macos

I wrote a python script and then made it into a mac app using a program called [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus). I noticed that if I make changes to the python source file inside the app's Resources folder, the app itself isn't updated. I'm wondering if there is a way I can update the app's source code without having to create a whole new app. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the `/usr/local/share/platypus/` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The actual source code is probably imbedded in the app itself.